# onunload and onbeforeunload not working

Tags: javascript

I have this script in my aspx page

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">     
    window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
        return 'Bye now!';
    }; 
</script>
```

But this is not invoked when I close the browser. I need to pop an alert asking the user to confirm. I need to do this in the aspx page using javascript. The browser I tried was mozilla firefox. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The following code should fix your issue:

```
(function () {
    window.unloader = function(e) {
       (e || window.event).returnValue = null;
       return null;
    };
    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", window.unloader);
})();
```

You are not going to be able to specify a message, it is defaulted by the browser.

Comment: It is working only with IE. Not with firefox and chrome

Comment: It works on all platforms. I use this exact code everywhere I need it. The wrapper I added might help..

Comment: With firefox the alert pops up for the first time and If I Click Leave this page. The next time when I open it again and close it the pop up does not occur. But when I open it for the third time and close it the pop up occours. Have you faced something like this

Comment: Where are you testing this? Because JSFiddle and other development environments might not allow this.  @SamDaniel

Comment: I did this using VS 2012